# In Azure databricks, How to create a table based on json config dynamically?

Tags: azure, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, azure-databricks

I have this tableConfig.json inside a ADLS container based location .

It has table specific details.

```
{
 "tableName":"employee",
 "databaseName": "dbo",
 "location" : "/mnt/clean/demo",
"colsList" : ["emp_id","emp_name","emp_city"]

}
```

Now I want to read that tableConfig.json in azure databricks python notebooks.
and dynamically create the create table and execute it, so that a delta table will be created

```
CREATE TABLE <databaseName.tableName>
(<colsList>)
USING delta
LOCATION <location>
```

Is there any approach we can do this ?

Basically i want a notebook to be created and if we execute it, then it should create the delta table as per json config

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is an option to create table based on the config file yet, but we can iterate through the `json(dict)` and create the table.

**`Example:`**

```
abc = [{
 "tableName":"employee",
 "databaseName": "dbo",
 "location" : "/mnt/clean/demo",
"colsList" : ["emp_id","emp_name","emp_city"]
}]

for i in abc:
  print(f"""spark.sql("CREATE TABLE {i['databaseName']}.{i['tableName']} USING delta location '{i['location']}'")""")

#spark.sql("CREATE TABLE dbo.employee USING delta location '/mnt/clean/demo'")
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i feel i can place a config file that has a json string as a reocrds, so that i can read it  from ADLS mnt location and convert each record as json(disct) and this can code can be used as template . Is my understanding correct

Comment: Yep.. and also we don't need to mention the column names while create delta table, as delta table gets the schema from your  delta table <location>.

Comment: Ok. you are saying  it takes columns information from datafame itself  and put it in table metadata (_delta_log) and keeps using  for future insert/update?

Comment: yes, that's right..!

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @notNull using `spark.sql` function to create table,
In addition to that, using dataframe you can follow below approach.

First, load the json data into dataframe and follow below steps.

If you having only these columns in list you create sql script to each record in dataframe and execute `spark.sql` function on them.

Below is your sample data, that I used.

[image]

create a function to make sql script and do udf register.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql.types import *

def gen_sql_script(tbl_name,db_name,loc,col_list):
    script=f"""
    CREATE TABLE {db_name}.{tbl_name}
    ({col_list[0]} int,{col_list[1]} string,{col_list[2]} string)
    USING delta
    LOCATION '{loc}';
    """
    return script
    
get_sql = udf(gen_sql_script,StringType())
```

Next, add new column called **script** calling above function.

```
df = df.withColumn("script",get_sql("tableName","databaseName","location","colsList"))
display(df)
```

[image]

Next, take only **script** column and run `spark.sql` function.

```
for i in df.select("script").collect():
    print(i['script'])
    spark.sql(f"{i['script']}")
```

[image]

This creates delta table in the given location.

Output

[image]

Comment: This is excellent. . really helpful and it can be used as Template for Create DDL